# How to set a prefab-cloned object position to (0,0,0) relative to parent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a UI panel.
In that panel, I want to add many times the same prefab (a small circle).
My code looks like this:

```c#
GameObject o = GameObject.Find("PanelCells");
Rect r = o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
RemoveAllChildren(o.transform);
for (float i = 0; i < 10; i += (float)1.0) {
    GameObject c = Instantiate(
        prefabCell, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, o.transform
    );
    c.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    Debug.Log("Before : " + c.transform.localPosition.ToString());
    c.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(i * 10, 0, 0);
    Debug.Log("After : " + c.transform.localPosition.ToString());
}
```

In the debug log I can see (for the #1 iteration log):

```
Before : (-288.1, 0.0, 1559.4)
After : (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

And when I go into the game, here are the position of the first prefabs: 288.11, 298.11, 308.11 and so on. So the `i * 10` worked...

If I set x to `0` manually from the editor when the game is running, it goes where I want it to go = to the `0` position.

I just want my dynamically generated prefabs to go to `(i * 10, 0, 0)` position, not what it is right now (`( (288.11 + i) * 10, 0, 0)`)

I want all of them to go to the x position `0` to `10`, `20`, `30` and so on.

What I mean by position (0,0,0) is "top left" relative to the parent.

Here's the screenshot of the parent configuration:

[image: screenshot of the parent configuration]

Here's my prefab:

[image: screenshot of my prefab]

And here's where I'd like the first element to be positioned when I set manually (0,0,0) to its position:

[image: screeshot of what I want]

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should be instantiating your object at `o.transform.position` instead of `Vector3.zero`. Instantiation is done in world space, even if you assign a parent.

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant note aswell, but why are you incrementing by floats.

Comment: He's using `i` in his Vector3, which only accepts float values. I'm assuming it's to avoid casting.

Comment: Is there any performance gain over casting the constant? He'd still need to explicitely cast something.

Comment: There's always a small performance gain whenever you can avoid casting... But he's still using casting (although it isn't needed) in his for loop.. `(float)1.0`.. Could easily write just `1.0f` (the f at the end is NOT a cast).

Comment: @BrandonMiller Thank you very much for this information, even though it doesn't actually answer to my question... I'll keep this in mind when I write a loop ...

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks for the clarification, I tried to keep your code intact and commented the notes. This should fix the prefab to it's relative anchored element.

```c#
public Transform t; //parent
public GameObject prefabCell;

for (float i = 0; i < 10; i += (float)1.0)
{
    GameObject c = Instantiate(prefabCell, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    // Removed the parent parameter and factored it out here.
    // The second parameter forces the worldpos to false
    c.transform.SetParent(t, false); 
    c.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    Debug.Log("Before : " + c.transform.localPosition.ToString());
    // Use anchored position when you manipulate UI elements,
    // the position property is counter-intuitive for canvas.
    c.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(i * 10, 0, 0);
    Debug.Log("After : " + c.transform.localPosition.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I want the positioning to be relative = to be in the parent, (0,0,0) = top left *into* the parent

Comment: isn't (0,0,0) of a parent, in the centre?

Comment: I would argue that your script is doing exactly what you want, but perhaps you're confused about the world units?

Comment: If you set the x position manually in the editor, that is the same thing as setting the objects `transform.position.x` property. Try switching from localPosition to plain position just to see if it works.

Comment: Brandon is on the right track i assume. If, logically you wanted to work in relative space, then use localPosition. But as a note, and i'm assuming i've read the question correctly:

( (288.11 + (i * 10), 0, 0) in world space = (i * 10, 0, 0) in relative parent space.

Comment: Here are the screenshot of my "parent" configuration, maybe this explains more than my words... but I'll try to get the width of the parent, divide it by 2 and substract it from the x position of the prefab.

Comment: If I do `c.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(c.transform.localPosition.x + (i * 10), 0, 0);` then it works. This way I add the opposite of x to bring them back to "top left" relative position... so you're right: (0,0,0) of a parent is in the centre... I didn't know about that, I'm totally new to both C# and Unity, I'm sorry. May I ask you to modify accordingly your answer so I check it as valid? Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Seems I was just looking for `anchoredPosition` property... thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: For anyone reading this here are the steps I have to perform: local -> world then world -> camera. And using `GetWorldCorners()` and `WorldToScreenPoint()` saved my day.